# Why is my iPhone application icon not working?

Tags: ios, xcode

I dragged an image named "star.jpeg" (57 x 57 pixels) into Supporting Files and typed the name of the image into the Icon List array in my plist file in XCode.

Why is the icon not working when I run my program in iOS Simulator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **.png** image for the icon.
Go to your projects **TARGET** and find ...

[image: USE png image , and look at the screenshot]

In addition to this, it is good practice to title your icon file "Icon.png" as you would call your splash image "Default.png".